# Calculating Cursor Position in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi All
I have a Form with a panel in it.
I want to move an image according to the cursor position.
I have a mouse over function, but how do i do the calculation right ? since the cursor position is from the monitor and the picturebox is from the panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Control.PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) method to convert screen coordinates to the local ones.  If you follow the MSDN link there's a good example that shows how to do that.

```
Point localCoordinates = myPictureBox.PointToClient(mouseScreenCoordinates);
```

Comment: it's still doesn't work as I want it. since everytime i move the application the position changes.

Comment: private void panelBoardGame_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point tempPoint = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
            m_PictureBoxCoin.PointToClient(tempPoint);
        }

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to do.  I'm not sure how to help you with the information you've provided so far.

Comment: `MouseEnter` happens once when the mouse cursor enters the control.  Do you want to keep moving the picture while the mouse moves?  I think you should be using `MouseMove` event in this case.

Comment: im trying to move an image while the mouse is moving inside the panel. I have a windows application which has a form inside it. inside the form i have a panel with labels are covering it all up. i added a picturebox with an image. and added it to the panel and i brought it to front. now I want to change the picturebox location according to the cursor position so that picturebox will move according to the cursor. the problem is that the cursor x,y coordinates starts at the topleft of your monitor while the picturebox x,y starts the topleft of the panel.

Comment: so everytime you move the application windows in the screen, the picturebox is in a different position and doens't stay with the cursor

Comment: Then you have to handle other events, like `Control.Move`.

Comment: ok, i followed your explination and the msdn, and its working now, thx for your help